# PHP - MySQL How can we use the memcached to execute bulk statments for load balancing?

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I like to use memcached to store periodic update sql statements and then execute them in bulk may be every 30 seconds so on.. how can i programmatically code this ?

I have tried following function but i am completely lost

```
function search_click($search_id)
{
    if (MEMCACHE === true) {
        $key          = __FUNCTION__.date("Y-m-d H:i",time());
            //. strtotime(date("Ymdhi", time()));
        $memcache_obj = new Memcache;
        $memcache_obj->connect('localhost', 11211);
        $sql = $memcache_obj->get($key);
        $sql.= " UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY search_si
                    SET count=count+1
                WHERE
                search_id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($search_id) . "' ; ";
        $memcache_obj->set($key,$sql);// repopulate the cache
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: What you put in a cache should be reproducible and SQL statements that need to be executed isn't one of those things; perhaps Redis is a better choice.

Comment: what do you mean ? all i want to do is cache them and execute them in bulk.

Comment: A cache doesn't guarantee that all cache items remain in the cache until you perform the bulk update.

Comment: why ? i have been relying on memcache for a long time, i havent encountered any problems, besides these queries are low priority